# Function call with a union return type

Tags: c++, error-handling

I have to use [this](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/freexl-1.0.0e-doxy-doc/freexl_8h.html#aef8dc850a668e82b9aa2efde78cc427a) library function in my code. This function returns [struct](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/freexl-1.0.0e-doxy-doc/structFreeXL__CellValue__str.html) including a `union` something like this:

```
union  (
     int   int_value;
    double   double_value;
    const char *   text_value;
} value;
```

I have to check the return type with a switch statement like the example in the referred page everytime I call this function. The real problem is
that I have to use this function more than once in my code, 15 times to be exact. It is very very frustrating to check the return type every-time and the resulting code is very ugly if it's not mess. I tried to wrap this code in a member function with return type auto. But it did not even compile.

- How can I do this?
- What should be the correct way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean check return type?  If it's returning "char*" or "int" or "double"?  Can you give example?

Comment: This question is extremely unclear. Where is the function that returns this `union`? How exactly are you calling it, and more important - how do you determine which attribute in the `union` is the relevant one?

Comment: sorry for the question. the function is this : http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/freexl-1.0.0e-doxy-doc/structFreeXL__CellValue__str.html

Comment: The problem seems to be that it's no function.

Comment: yeah sorry again. its not the function its the return type. anyway i edited question for correct links

Comment: There are many links in your question, but no example code of how you are using (or trying to use the library). That does not fit common rules of SO. You should carefully read [http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask] and edit your post.

Comment: @SergeBallesta dont be ignorant. you can clearly see the example on the referred page!

Comment: As I can see now from your given links my answer fits to your problem. If not, please precise your question :-)

Comment: You can pass it as an argument(I am using it in one of my projects).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your example code will not fit a real world code!

If you have a union which acts as a return type, you must have a idea which field of the union holds a valid value. So I expect you have something like:

```
struct SOME_TYPE
{
    enum { IS_TEXT, IS_INT, IS_DOUBLE } valid_type;

    union return_val 
    {
        char* text_val;
        int int_val;
        double double_val;
    }
 };
```

And if your return type contains such a type info ( which is a must ) it is easy to create `casting class` which takes as argument this struct/union. This class now can do any kind of tests for you, typesafe! and automatically. And it can also generate ( factory pattern ) subclasses, which can do all the actions which are only valid for the given value type.

```
class UnionHandler
{
     public:
         UnionHandler( const SOME_TYPE& val )
         {
              switch ( val.valid_type) 
              {
                  case... whatever you want
              }
         }

     bool Check() { // whatever you want }

}
```

But at all: Avoid unions!!!!!!!!